# Python multiprocessing daemon vs non-daemon vs main

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm learning multiprocessing in Python while I found this odd behaviour between daemon and non-daemon process with respect to the main process.
**My Code:**

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(name,num):
    print name, 'Starting'
    time.sleep(num)
    print name, 'Exiting'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'main starting'
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=("p1",7,))
    p2=multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=("p2",5,))
    p2.daemon=True
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    time.sleep(4)
    print 'main exiting'
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
main starting
p1 Starting
p2 Starting
main exiting
p1 Exiting
```

Expected Output:

```
main starting
p1 Starting
p2 Starting
main exiting
p2 Exiting
p1 Exiting
```

After few searches, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720281/why-is-a-python-multiprocessing-daemon-process-not-printing-to-standard-output) and inserted the following line to my code.

```
logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)
```

And the output I got is,

```
main starting
[INFO/p1] child process calling self.run()
p1 Starting
[INFO/p2] child process calling self.run()
p2 Starting
main exiting
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[INFO/MainProcess] calling terminate() for daemon p2
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process p2
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process p1
p1 Exiting
[INFO/p1] process shutting down
[INFO/p1] process exiting with exitcode 0
```

As per my understanding,

- When a main process exits, it terminates all of its child daemon processes. (Which can be seen here)
- A main process can not exit before all of its child non-daemon processes exit.

But here, why the main process is trying to shut down before p1 exits?

- p1 starts and sleeps for 7 seconds.
- p2 starts and sleeps for 5 seconds.
- main process sleeps for 4 seconds.
- main process wakes up after 4 seconds and waits for p1 to exit.
- p2 wakes up after 5 seconds and exits.
- p1 wakes up after 7 seconds and exits.
- main process exits.

Wouldn't be the above a normal time-line for the above program?

Can anyone please explain what's happening here and why?

**EDIT**

After adding the line `p1.join()` at the end of the code, I'm getting the following output:

```
main starting
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
p1 Starting
[INFO/Process-2] child process calling self.run()
p2 Starting
main exiting
p2 Exiting
[INFO/Process-2] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
p1 Exiting
[INFO/Process-1] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see

```
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process p1
```

it means the main process has not exited yet -- it's in **the process** of shutting down, but of course will not be done shutting down until that `join` returns... which will happen only once the joined process is done.

So the timeline is indeed as you expect it to be -- but since that `join` to `p1` is the very last think the `main` process ever does, you don't see that in the output or logging from it.  (main has taken all the termination-triggered action, but as a process it's still alive until then).

To verify, use (on a Unixy system) `ps` from another terminal while running this (perhaps with slightly longer delays to help you check): you will never see a single Python process running out of this complex -- there will be two (main and p1) until the end.

Comment: I'm not worried about `p1`. `join` to `p1` is the last thing the `main` process ever does and this will happen after 7 seconds. Before that `p2` shouldn't be terminated forcibly by the `main` process. Since `p2` has a 5 seconds of sleep, it should wake up from it and should print `p2 Exiting` before `p1`'s 7 seconds sleep is over. Which is not the case here.

Comment: Main process forcibly terminates daemon processes as part of its shutting-down activities (before waiting for p1, which is the very last thing it does -- multiprocessing's specs don't force the order to be this way but neither do they forbid it in any way, shape, or form); p2 is a daemon process; hence, p2 gets forcibly terminated.  Not sure why you expected otherwise, but, whatever you expected, it doesn't follow from the specs, and (without any violation of the specs) it does not happen.

Comment: My question is, since `p1` is non-daemon process, before `p1` exits, how the main process is starting its shut-down activities. I couldn't find any proper specs regarding multiprocessing. In the `docs` it's not mentioned. After reading some topics here and there, I guessed the expected output. Given that, if I decrease the timer of `p2`'s sleep to 4 seconds, I'm getting my expected output.

Comment: The main process can (and does) perform all shut-down activities it "wants" (in the current implementation, all of them:-), as long as it doesn't actually exit until p1 has also exited.  The specs, per https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html, are: "When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes ... non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically".  No constraints in the specs wrt the order in which these termination activities (and others, such as calling `atexit`-registers functions) are done.  Sure, change delays if you need to!

Comment: Can you please refer to the **EDIT** part of the question and tell me what's the different action it's doing internally? Except for printing what I'm expecting. In both the cases, it's calling `join` to `p1`. In the 1st one it's done automatically and in the second, I'm doing it. But behaves differently.

Comment: @RatDon, when you `join` explicitly, it's obviously done **before** the termination actions of the main process, since that statement is then part of the main process's explicit code.

Comment: @RatDon, you're welcome, but an upvote and ideally an accept would be better than just "thanks":-)

Comment: Sorry. Forgot that part. :P. Upvoted. But can you include some of the parts of your comments in the answer so that it'll be better to understand from the answer rather than the comments. So it'll be helpful for some if they find this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Python Multiprocess| Daemon & Join

Question end up adding more wait towards the behavior of daemon flag and join method, hence here a quick explanation with a simple script.

1. The daemon process is terminated automatically before the main program exits, to avoid leaving orphaned processes running but is not terminated with the main program. So **any outstanding processes left by the daemoned function won't run!**
2. However if the join() method is called on the daemoned function then the main programm **will wait the left over processes.**

### INPUT

```
        import multiprocessing
        import time
        import logging


        def daemon():
            p = multiprocessing.current_process()
            print('Starting:', p.name, p.pid, flush=True)
            print('---' * 15)
            time.sleep(2)
            print('===' * 15 + ' < ' + f'Exiting={p.name, p.pid}' + ' > ' + '===' * 15, flush=True)



        def non_daemon():
            p = multiprocessing.current_process()
            print('Starting:', p.name, p.pid, flush=True)
            print('---'*15)
            print('===' * 15 + ' < ' + f'Exiting={p.name, p.pid}' + ' > ' + '===' * 15, flush=True)


        if __name__ == '__main__':
            print('==='*15 + ' < ' + 'MAIN PROCESS' + ' > ' + '==='*15)
            logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)
            # DAEMON
            daemon_proc = multiprocessing.Process(name='MyDaemon', target=daemon)
            daemon_proc.daemon = True

            # NO-DAEMON
            normal_proc = multiprocessing.Process(name='non-daemon', target=non_daemon)
            normal_proc.daemon = False

            daemon_proc.start()
            time.sleep(2)
            normal_proc.start()

            # daemon_proc.join()
```

---

### OUTPUT NO JOIN METHOD##

```
============================================= < MAIN PROCESS > =============================================
Starting: MyDaemon 8448
---------------------------------------------
[INFO/MyDaemon] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[INFO/MainProcess] calling terminate() for daemon MyDaemon
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process MyDaemon
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process non-daemon
Starting: non-daemon 6688
---------------------------------------------
============================================= < Exiting=('non-daemon', 6688) > =============================================
[INFO/non-daemon] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/non-daemon] process shutting down
[INFO/non-daemon] process exiting with exitcode 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

The function daemon() is 'spleeping' 2 second, hence as Python reaches the bottom of the script the program shut down but not daemon().

- Note:

`[INFO/MainProcess] calling terminate() for daemon MyDaemon`

Now if the last line of the script `daemon_proc.join()` is not commented.

---

### OUTPUT + JOIN METHOD

```
============================================= < MAIN PROCESS > =============================================
Starting: MyDaemon 13588
---------------------------------------------
[INFO/MyDaemon] child process calling self.run()
============================================= < Exiting=('MyDaemon', 13588) > =============================================
[INFO/MyDaemon] process shutting down
[INFO/MyDaemon] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[INFO/MainProcess] calling join() for process non-daemon
Starting: non-daemon 13608
---------------------------------------------
============================================= < Exiting=('non-daemon', 13608) > =============================================
[INFO/non-daemon] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/non-daemon] process shutting down
[INFO/non-daemon] process exiting with exitcode 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```