# python's multiprocessing module's join() when its process is a daemon

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm confused why the following block of code works the way it does. When a process is a daemon and doesn't call join() vs when it does call join(). When it doesn't call join(), it appears that the main process terminates and the daemon process both terminate after the main process terminates:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
        print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    #p.join()
```

output:

```
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 290
process id: 4793
```

join() is called:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
        print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

output:

```
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 290
process id: 4807
function f
module name: __main__
parent process: 4807
process id: 4808
hello bob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. When the main process terminates, the deamon process will also terminate.
This page will give you more details:  [Why is a Python multiprocessing daemon process not printing to standard output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720281/why-is-a-python-multiprocessing-daemon-process-not-printing-to-standard-output)