# mutiprocessing with "spawn" context cannot access shared variables in Linux

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have to use the Process method with "spawn" context in Linux. Then I write a sample code as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Value
import multiprocessing

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, m_val):
        print("step1")
        self.m_val = m_val
        print("step2")
        self.m_val_val = m_val.value
        self.prints()
    def prints(self):
        print("self.m_val_val:%d"%self.m_val_val)


def main(m_val):
    t = Test(m_val)

if __name__   == "__main__":
    N = 2
    procs = []
    v = Value("i",10)
    for i in range(0,N):
        proc_i = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Process(target=main,args=(v,))
        proc_i.daemon=True
        procs.append(proc_i)
    for i in range(0,N):
        procs[i].start()
    
    for i in range(0,N):
        procs[i].join()
```

When I run this code in Linux, it will print:

```
step1
step2
step1
step2
```

while in Windows, the print content will be:

```
step1
step2
self.m_val_val:10
step1
step2
self.m_val_val:10
```

Besides, there is no error information printed on the screen.
So, how can I solve this problem, i.e., how to use multiprocessing Value in among processes while using "spawn" context in Linux?

Comment: I reproduce the issue. I still not have an explanation. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27720367/11384184) on how to add logging.

Comment: The problem comes from accessing the `.value` from the `synchronized wrapper`. But I have no clue what is the problem. My debugger can't show me the frame, but the process exits durint it. While on Windows, after a few frames it continues to execute the script. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating `Value` in the default context, which is *fork* on Unix.

You can resolve this by setting the default start context to `"spawn"`:

```py
multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")  # Add this
v = Value("i",10)
```

Better yet, create the `Value` in the context explicitly:

```py
# v = Value("i",10)                         # Change this
ctx = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")  # to this
v = ctx.Value("i",10)                       #
for i in range(0,N):
    # proc_i = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Process(target=main,args=(v,))  # (Optional) Refactor this
    proc_i = ctx.Process(target=main,args=(v,))                                     # to this
```

## Reference

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods:

> *spawn*
>
> Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows and macOS.
>
> *fork*
>
> Available on Unix only. The default on Unix.

> Note that objects related to one context may not be compatible with processes for a different context. In particular, locks created using the *fork* context cannot be passed to processes started using the *spawn* or *forkserver* start methods.

---

## Reproducing this issue on macOS

This issue can be reproduced on macOS with Python < 3.8.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods:

> *Changed in version 3.8*: On macOS, the *spawn* start method is now the default.

To reproduce this issue on macOS with Python 3.8 and above:

```py
multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")  # Add this
v = Value("i",10)
```

## Error message and stack trace

> OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/python/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/path/to/python/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 18, in main
    t = Test(m_val)
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.m_val_val = m_val.value
  File "<string>", line 3, in getvalue
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```